# Organizing ASP.NET resource files in folders based on language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, embedded-resource

In my application's root `App_LocalResources` I've created several resource files (`.resx`) to localize my application for multiple languages.

For Spanish, I copied over the default resource files and added `.es` before the `.resx` so that the full name is `myresource.es.resx`. When I change the UI culture, the language change works fine.

However, when I wanted to organize my Spanish resource files in one folder (tried: `es-Es`, `es` and `Spanish`) under the `App_LocalResources` folder, the application stopped recognizing the resource files.

Is there a convention of how to organize resources files for each language so that I don't have a single folder with all the resource files?

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't doing resource-file-per-page, use `App_GlobalResources` instead. You can organize your files into a folder structure using this method. IIRC, your file names have to be unique in the *whole tree*, not just in each branch. I've had good success naming the files by site *section*, but YMMV of course.

Here's an MSDN article that should help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

Answer (score -1):

What is the name of the resource DLL in the resource folder? It should not contain the locale id anymore (so es\myresource.dll, not es\myresource.es.dll)